# Excel: How to prevent that selecting a value of a dropdwon field deletes formula?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-formula, vlookup

In my sheet I have cells with a dropdown field and simultaneously a VLOOKUP formula in the formula bar of each cell.

However if I select a value in a dropdown field, the VLOOKUP formula in that cell gets deleted.

Is it possible to prevent this?
This would be of good use if you delete values out of these cells via the DEL/ENTF key (which makes it a blank cell with a dropdown field) and then the formula is valid again. :-)

Comment: This is more complicated than you think; remember that a dropdown simply allows you to change the value in a cell (to one of a predetermined list). Cells cannot contain mulitple formulas at the same time. In order to do this you would need a significant VBA project which tracks what formulas used to be, and then bring them back automatically. If you don't use VBA then it is not recommended that you go this route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright it looks like you aren't comfortable with a VBA solution, so I will give you an alternative method. This will require you to have an in-between column which you will likely want to hide from the end user.

Assume your VLOOKUP formulas are in column A. Hide column A from your user. Assume column B will now hold your dropdown selection cells. This will be the user input column, but it will not be the output column. The output column (used by formulas, and should also indicate to users that it is the current result) will be column C. In column C put the following formula (starting at C1, dragging down):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),A1,B1)
```

If a user has not selected anything in the dropdown list in B1, B1 will be blank. In that case, C1 will default to the VLOOKUP result found in A1. If the user has selected anything in B1, C1 will default to that value.

For this to work you will probably need to make sure that one of the available options in each dropdown list is an empty cell (not "", which isnt technically blank).

Comment: Thanks for that solution mate as I have no clue about VBA. However your latest solution is also not practical for me because in my sheet i have approximiately 10 features listed for which I have to apply the procedure above. If every feature has two columns it will definitely looks bloated with 20 columns unless there is an option which hides the B-columns also when you enable some option or at least hides the B column when I print the worksheet. :-)

But anyways, I am very grateful for your offered solutions. :-)